# What's the right way to fill plhs[] in a MEX file?

Tags: matlab

Is `plhs[]` preallocated to some size?

Specifically, if the user hasn't provided any output args, can I still assign to `plhs[0]`? `plhs[i]`, i>0?

Or should I check nlhs to see that there's the appropriate amount of output args?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plhs` has the size given ny `nlhs`. Except, if `nlhs == 0`, you may assign to `plhs[0]` in order to provide a value for `ans` - if you want so.

There are functions which differentiate between "targetless" calls and calls with assignment. E.g., `a = path` does other stuff than `path`, while `sum([1 2 3])` does the same as `a = sum([1 2 3])`. This said distinction is the reason for that.

Comment: thanks! do you know where to find good documentation for this?

Comment: Alas, no, except http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/apiref/mexfunction.html. I derived it by conclusion.